# Appium iOS : How to find child element of an element

Tags: ios, selenium, appium

Appium : 1.3.1
Mac OS X 10.9.4

I face a scenario where I need to iterate a loop through all the results and click on 1 of them if the text matches.

As per hierarchy the structure looks like this

```
  >UIATableView
     > UIATableCell
            >UIAStaticText
     > UIATableCell
            >UIAStaticText
     > UIATableCell
            >UIAStaticText
     > UIATableCell
            >UIAStaticText
```

Click action works fine if I take List as UIATableCell.

I took list listingResults as @iOSFindBy(className="UIATableCell")

```
  for (WebElement resultNum : listingResults) {

    resultText= resultNum.getText().trim();

    if(!resultText.contains("more option")){
        System.out.println(resultText);
     }

  }
```

resultNum.getText() is not returning any text. And for text I need to look into "UIAStaticText".

Q. I'm trying to use findelement and expecting resultNum.findelement(By.className("UIAStaticText")).getText() to return the text. It is not working...

[image]

Comment: I think we'd be better able to help if you provided a sample of the HTML.

Comment: @Richard- I beleive you are asking for xml as it is iOS native app. I'm not sure how to get the xml but I've added a screenshot above. Please see if that helps or it would be great if you guide me how to get the xml or html.

Comment: Ahh.. I got the answer here..

https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2814

"Sometimes the text is indeed ''. Did you also try getAttribute('label'), getAttribute('value'), and getAttribute('name')?"

getAttribute('name') worked in my case..

Answer (score 0):

I finally got the answer [here](https://github.com/appium/appium/issues/2814)

As per Jlipps comment:

Sometimes the text is indeed ''. Did you also try getAttribute('label'), getAttribute('value'), and getAttribute('name')?

And getAttribute('name') worked in my case